# Loading images for HTML in jboss

Tags: html, jboss

I have HTML pages that I put inside temp folder(Outside WEB-INF directory). I have used some images inside my HTML pages. I have put those images also in temp folder and then I created my war file. When I run that in localhost, Images are not loaded into HTML pages. It shows all the contents except Images. 
Then I created a folder images outside WEB-INF directory, put all image files into that and created war file. But the result was same. Can anyoe tell Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is this question so simple that no one wants to answer or so difficult that no one knows to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked whether the .gif file is in Uppercase or Lower case(you can get this information when you make the war file from command prompt). 
If the "gif" is in Uppercase in the war file and you have given it as `<image background="bg.gif">`, then change it to `<image background="bg.GIF">`. I think this is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks man! That is where I was making mistake. Genius u r! It solved my big problem. Thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 1):

What might really help is if you can share the structure of your WAR file and also a sample html snippet that shows how you are referring to those image files. The problem maybe the way you are referring to those image files.

Let me answer this question with an example

Lets assume your war structure is as follows

```
webapp.war
 |
 |---> WEB-INF
 |------|
 |      ----> classes
 |---> index.html
 |---> images
 |-------|
 |       ----> logo.gif
```

The way you'd refer to the image file is as follows

If you are doing this correctly and still not able to view the image files, you need to share some more details as I mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: My war structure is same as you mentioned above. How do i need to point those images into my html file. As in now I have given the path as <body background="logo.gif">. Should I give it as <body background="images/logo.gif">. Or is there any other format used for this?

Comment: If your images are stored in a folder named "images" as I showed above, you'd have to use <body background="images/logo.gif">

Comment: My war structure is same as urs. I have stored images into images folder. Then I have used tag as <body background="images/logo.gif">. But still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you for serving static content without modifying the war file. The first is what I would recommended.

1. Setup Apache as front end proxy and use Apache to serve the static content
2. Copy the static content into ROOT.war under directory say static and then reference the static content as "/static/logo.gif".

Comment: I tried the 2nd method. Its not working.Is it "/static/logo.gif" or I have to give something else before the first slash(/).

Comment: If you have copied it to "ROOT.war/static/logo.gif", then yes, its "/static/logo.gif". Once you create this folder+file you should be able to verify it by hitting http://hostname:8080/static.logo.gif

Comment: :I tried this also. I am getting the following error HTTP STATUS 404

Comment: In that case, does anything work ? Does hostname:8080 work ? If you copy html files instead of gif's to that folder, does it work ?