# Images, css not loading in tomcat-6.. getting 404 on web page

Tags: html, tomcat6

My application is deployed on apache-tomcat 6.0.28.

When I deploy my app, Images are not loaded into HTML pages (404 error). It shows all the contents except Images.

I m facing exactly same problem as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766160/loading-images-for-html-in-jboss). My web app structure is

```
search-app.war
 |
 |---> WEB-INF
 |       |
 |      ----> classes
 |      ----> lib
 |      ----> pages
 |       |
 |       ----> xx.jsp
 |---> index.html
 |---> css
 |      |
 |      ----> search.css
 |---> images
 |       |
 |       ----> logo.gif
```

I m accessing logo.gif from xx.jsp, here is a code

```
<div id="logo">
<img src="search-app/images/logo.gif" alt="search" style="padding-top:150px;" />
</div>
```

I tried every other option of src but every time I get 404 for that image.

If i hit this - http://[localhost]:8080/search-app/images/logo.gif on a browser, still its 404.

Same issue with css -

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/search-app/css/search.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

This error is killing me now!! Please help. Thanks.

Comment: First, open up your war file with some ZIP tool (e.g., Ark or File Roller on Linux and WinRAR/WinZip on Windows) and check if the bundle contains the image file stored in the images folder. If the file is there, test deleting the tomcat `work` directory (completely, it will get regenerated automatically the next time you start the server) and refresh the browser using `Ctrl+F5`

Comment: No, that didn't help. images folder is present in the war. Then I deleted the work dir and restarted the tomcat but still i m seeing 404 for that image resource :(

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- Try using Google Chrome, open up the developer tools tab by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and inspect the resources in the `Resources` tab, check if your image is there. Check if says `Failed to load resource`
- Change the `<img src="search-app/images/logo.gif" alt="search" style="padding-top:150px;" />` for `<img src="images/logo.gif" alt="search" style="padding-top:150px;" />` (delete the `search-app/` from the image url)
- Check that you're accessing the correct version of your application, if you deploy from an IDE such like Eclipse, it will explode your war in a `wtpwebapps` directory instead of `webapps`. sometimes confusion arises from having multiple deployments (manual, automatic from IDE, build script, etc) check that
- Check if the image is not corrupted (although this shouldn't cause a `404` error)
- Create a test webapp war with only one jsp file and an image, and test it
- Check if the dirname contains any extra space at the end like *"images "*

Comment: hey I placed a hack to make it work. I moved the images dir outside the search-app dir itself. So now the images dir is right under tomcat/webapps .. I m not sure if this is correct way, I must have screwed something in web.xml url mapping setup.. Does that ring any bells? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the `images` dir name doesn't contain any space? They can look invisible in the os file explorer, check that trying to rename the dir or creating a new dir (be careful writing the name) and test again

Comment: There is no space. Only after moving the image dir outside, its working. I think something is wrong the way I ve configured the controller mapping in web.xml.. Atleast for now I m not blocked... I will come to this tomorrow. Appreciate your help again.

Comment: Do you have any servlet filter that blocks the image dir content from being served? Can you post the relevant parts of your `web.xml`?

Comment: Sorry I was into completing the other priority items. Appreciate that you are helping me out. here is the web.xml -

Comment: '<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>'

Answer (score 1):

When you copy images/scripts to there respective locations physically, you need to come back to your eclipse window and refresh the project. Thats it!!!!!
Works like a charm.